# HDP docker-image gets stuck while starting

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-sandbox

I was trying Hortonworks Data Platform docker image. I could load the image but while starting HDP with the script they provide '[start_sandbox-hdp.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hortonworks/data-tutorials/master/tutorials/hdp/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/assets/start_sandbox-hdp.sh)' it gets stuck on "Waiting for Ambari Agent to connect".

I tried a couple of times and again get stuck at the point. What should I do? The followed the official doc [here.](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/section/3/#deploy-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to see what Docker version you are using. I had this exact same problem with Docker 17.11 and 17.12. When I installed a version earlier than those, this problem went away for me. Specifically, I used Docker 17.09.

I should note that I think Docker still doesn't have a good mechanism for indicating their previous releases. You can use this:

https://gist.github.com/franklinyu/5e0bb9d6c0d873f33c78415dd2ea4138

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue there is that docker images for HDP are broken. I was not able to run them with latest Docker on Linux. So the only thing you can do is to use Virtualbox image or build your own Docker containers.

Here is very long manual how to assemble latest freely available Ambari HDP stack for Docker http://mixeddev.info/articles/2020/12/10/run-apache-ambari-hdp-hdf-in-docker.html